# Group values on same property

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
[
    {unit: 35, brand: 'CENTURY'},
    {unit: 35, brand: 'BADGER'},
    {unit: 25, brand: 'CENTURY'},
    {unit: 15, brand: 'CENTURY'},
    {unit: 25, brand: 'XEGAR'}
]
```

What I want is to mix the jsons with same unit value, joining the brands comma separated, so that the result array would be:

```
[
    {unit: 35, brand: 'CENTURY, BADGER'},
    {unit: 25, brand: 'CENTURY, XEGAR'},
    {unit: 15, brand: 'CENTURY'}
]
```

Someone suggest me to use `filter()`, I'm reading about it at MDN, and something that I don't understand is how could I use the last invoked argument:

> callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> 1. the value of the element
> 2. the index of the element
> 3. the Array object being traversed

I mean, I know it is the complete array, but if I'm already filtering it, how would that help me?

```
vm.products.filter(
    function(product, index, products){
        //How do I compare here if product === any product in products
        //and then add mix them up?
    }
)
```

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" - asking how to do something on Stack Overflow itself doesn't constitute research.

Comment: I'm reading about `.filter` and `.reduce` at mdn (thanks so chat) but I don't really get how to do it @JamesThorpe

Comment: Perhaps include some of your attempts at using them then, then it becomes a question of why some specific code that you're working with isn't working, rather than a "write my code for me" question.  Although as always, it seems others are happy to comply...

Comment: Thnks @JamesThorpe for your suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the elements and generate new array

```js
var arr = [{
    unit: 35,
    brand: 'CENTURY'
  }, {
    unit: 35,
    brand: 'BADGER'
  }, {
    unit: 25,
    brand: 'CENTURY'
  }, {
    unit: 15,
    brand: 'CENTURY'
  }, {
    unit: 25,
    brand: 'XEGAR'
  }],
  ind = [],
  res = [];

// iterate over the array using forEach or for loop
arr.forEach(function(v) {
  // checking unit value is in `ind` array  
  var eleIn = ind.indexOf(v.unit);
  if (eleIn === -1) {
    // pushing unit value to `ind` array
    ind.push(v.unit);
    // pushing array element to `res` array
    res.push(v);
  } else
    // else case updating brand value
    res[eleIn].brand += ', ' + v.brand;
})

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do it?, maybe using `.filter` ?

Comment: @feniixx, I added a `filter` solution, though I don't think it's more performant, readable or simple than this one.

Answer (score 1):

OP asked for a solution using `filter`. Here is one, though not better than the rest

```js
var arr = [{
  unit: 35,
  brand: 'CENTURY'
}, {
  unit: 35,
  brand: 'BADGER'
}, {
  unit: 25,
  brand: 'CENTURY'
}, {
  unit: 15,
  brand: 'CENTURY'
}, {
  unit: 25,
  brand: 'XEGAR'
}]
var done = [];

var arr2 = arr.map(function(obj) {
  if (done.indexOf(obj.unit)>=0) return;
  done.push(obj.unit);
  var arrIn = arr.filter(function(objIn) {
    return obj.unit == objIn.unit;
  });
  return {
    unit: arrIn[0].unit,
    brand: arrIn.map(function(obj2) {
      return obj2.brand;
    }).join(',')
  };
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var objArray = [
    {unit: 35, brand: 'CENTURY'},
    {unit: 35, brand: 'BADGER'},
    {unit: 25, brand: 'CENTURY'},
    {unit: 15, brand: 'CENTURY'},
    {unit: 25, brand: 'XEGAR'}
];

    var output = {};
    var outputArr = [];
    for( var counter = 0; counter < objArray.length; counter++ )
    {
       var unit = objArray[ counter ].unit;
       if ( !output [ unit ] )
       {
          output [ unit ] = [];
       }
       output [ unit ].push( objArray[ counter ].brand );
    }
     for ( var unit in output )
    {
      outputArr.push( { unit: unit, brand: output[ unit ].join( "," ) } );
    }
   console.log( outputArr );
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a somewhat generic solution at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JosephGarrone/cgrk7bru/2/).

What is does is take a `field` to group the data on. When it finds a match, it then modifies the first object that had that `field` and adds all the properties on the other instances that match that `field` to it. IE: If you were to add extra fields on a `unit 35` instance below, they would be copied to the combined instance. This can be turned off by commenting out the inner most `else` statement.

Here is the code

```
var data = [
    {unit: 35, brand: 'CENTURY'},
    {unit: 35, brand: 'BADGER'},
    {unit: 25, brand: 'CENTURY'},
    {unit: 15, brand: 'CENTURY'},
    {unit: 25, brand: 'XEGAR'}
];

function groupBy(field, data) {
  var result = [];
  var ignore = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var current = data[i];
    var isNew = true;

    // Find matching elements
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      var test = data[j];

      if (test != current && result.indexOf(test) == -1 && ignore.indexOf(test) == -1) {
        // If their fields match
        if (test[field] == current[field]) {
          for (var key in test) {
            if (test.hasOwnProperty(key) && key != field) {
              if (current.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var currentValues = current[key].split(", ");
                currentValues.push(test[key]);
                current[key] = currentValues.join(", ");
              } else {
                current[key] = test[key];
              }
            }
          }

          // Add to ignore list
          ignore.push(test);
        }
      }
    }

    if (ignore.indexOf(current) == -1) {
      result.push(current);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var newData = groupBy('unit', data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Outputs:

```
[
    {"unit":35,"brand":"CENTURY, BADGER"},
    {"unit":25,"brand":"CENTURY, XEGAR"},
    {"unit":15,"brand":"CENTURY"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-destructive solution with `Array.prototype.filter()` and a temporary object.

```js
var array = [{ unit: 35, brand: 'CENTURY' }, { unit: 35, brand: 'BADGER' }, { unit: 25, brand: 'CENTURY' }, { unit: 15, brand: 'CENTURY' }, { unit: 25, brand: 'XEGAR' }];

function filter(a) {
    var o = {};
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)).filter(function (b) {
        if (!(b.unit in o)) {
            o[b.unit] = b;
            return true;
        }
        o[b.unit].brand += ', ' + b.brand;
    });
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filter(array), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```